# PHP: ImageMagic not loading from Apache (MAMP) but from CLI

Tags: php, apache, imagemagick, mamp, osx-mavericks

I manage to install ImageMagick on OSX Mavericks + MAMP 2.0 which has php 5.3.6.
But Imagick isnt loading through apache. It works on CLI. As an example I have following code,

```
<?php

if (!extension_loaded('imagick')) {
  echo "Imagick is not loaded";

}else{ 
  echo "Imagick is loaded";
  var_dump(Imagick::getVersion());
}

?>
```

if I run this on browser it says,

```
Imagick is not loaded
```

if I run this on CLI,

`$ /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/php /Development/test.php`

```
Imagick is loaded
array(2) {
  ["versionNumber"]=>
  int(1672)
  ["versionString"]=>
  string(68) "ImageMagick 6.8.8-3 Q16 x86_64 2014-02-19 http://www.imagemagick.org"
}
```

CLI and Apache both loads the same php.ini, but if I do a phpinfo on browser it does NOT show Imagick extension as loaded, but if I do

```
$ /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/php -i | less
```

I can see,

```
imagick

imagick module => enabled
imagick module version => 3.1.2
imagick classes => Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator
ImageMagick version => ImageMagick 6.8.8-3 Q16 x86_64 2014-02-19 http://www.imagemagick.org
ImageMagick copyright => Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
ImageMagick release date => 2014-02-19
ImageMagick number of supported formats:  => 214
ImageMagick supported formats => 3FR,
```

Any ideas whats really happening here?

Comment: Did you restart the apache server?

Comment: Definitely I did... more than once :)